# interchangeably using FILE pointer and file descriptor

Tags: linux, file, io

How can I insure that the `FILE*` file descriptor state stays in sync when I call lower level function API like read/write on its file descriptor given by `fileno()` function instead of calling `fread`/`fwrite`.
The scenario I am thinking of is:

```
fp = fopen(...)
fd = fileno(fp)
read(...,fd)
```

After the above `read(...,fd)`, I want the `fp` (`FILE*`) to be positioned correctly after the bytes read. `ftell` and `feof` should still point the correct information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is more complex than you think:

The `FILE*`-based API (e.g. `fread()`) uses an internal buffer and depending on the C library (version) you use, you have to consider that ...

- ... `fopen()` might already read bytes into the buffer, so the file pointer of `fp` is 0, but the file pointer of `fd` is not 0.

  This means that you have to ensure that `fd` is in sync with `fp` before using `fd`.
- ... the C library might assume that the file pointer of `fd` is only modified by `FILE`-based calls.

  This means that you have to restore the file pointer of `fd` between using `read()` and calling any function based on `FILE`.

So the following code might work:

```
fp = fopen(...)
fd = fileno(fp)
/* Remember file position of fd */
oldpos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
/* Ensure file position of fd is in sync with fp */
lseek(fd, ftell(fp), SEEK_SET);
read(...,fd)
/* Get new file position of fd */
newpos = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
/* Restore old file position of fd */
lseek(fd, oldpos, SEEK_SET);
/* Keep fp in sync with fd */
fseek(fp, newpos, SEEK_SET);
```

(However, there is no guarantee that this code works with every C library that exists.)